# Export database schema with SQLDeveloper CLI

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

In the GUI-Version of SQLDeveloper, there is the possibility to do an export of a database-schema (Tools - Database Export). The result is a SQL-File ("export.sql" by default).

Now I read that since Version 4 there is a CLI-Version of SQL-Developer called "sdcli.exe". Is it possible to do the same task with it? The result should be a SQL-File containing the DDL of the schema.
Unfortunately I wasn't able to find a suitable command via "-help". But maybe I'm just overlooking it.

I know there are other possibilities to export a db-schema, but in my use case I would prefer a human readable SQL-File and I'm trying to avoid writing my own script ;-)

Comment: Which command line tool do you mean? SQLcl is the current one. (You can get the early adopter version [from OTN](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html)). That can [generate the DDL for individual objects](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2015/04/generating-table-ddl-via-sqlcl-with-and-without-storage-clauses/) but you need to know the names, so it's not quite the same. And [sqlformat](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2015/02/a-quick-4-1-trick-set-sqlformat/) can generate insert statements, but doesn't sound like you want those.

Comment: When you download the current SQLDeveloper you can find the tool under "sqldeveloper/bin/sdcli.exe". I want to get a human readable "snapshot" of the overall DDL without knowing the single objects.